# Oracle SQL -Populate data based on latest version and business date

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

1. We receive daily price data multiple times from upstream system

[image: List item]

2. Admin can approve directly or update the price and approve

Direct Approval - No version increment
[image]

Update & Approve

[image]

3. Admin can correct the price for already approved data (for one year period for audit purpose or tally the price)

[image]

My Sample data

[image]

Expected Output

for 15th

[image]

For 16th

[image]

We need to pull latest version based on business date.
We are using below query to pull the data and it works as expected but takes more time. I need help to improve the performance

I am adding sample data and my table contains at least millions of record ie 13 months of record which I need to pull daily data which is close 20 thousand records.

Please share better way of populating the same instead of my approach

Please find the query execution here - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/757c2/13

Please avoid update the query in the same fiddle page

Thanks in advance

```
WITH LATEST_ITEMS AS (
  SELECT ORIGINAL.ITEM_ID, ORIGINAL.ITEM_SUB_ID, ORIGINAL.BUSINESS_DT,ORIGINAL.REPORT_DT,
  ORIGINAL.VERSION, ORIGINAL.STATE, ORIGINAL.PRICE FROM ITEM_PRICE ORIGINAL
  JOIN (
    SELECT ITEM_ID, ITEM_SUB_ID, BUSINESS_DT, MAX(VERSION) MAX_VERSION FROM ITEM_PRICE 
    WHERE STATE IN ('RECEIVED', 'APPROVED') 
    GROUP BY ITEM_ID, ITEM_SUB_ID, BUSINESS_DT) 
      MAX_VERSION
  ON NVL(MAX_VERSION.ITEM_SUB_ID,0) = NVL(ORIGINAL.ITEM_SUB_ID,0)
  AND MAX_VERSION.ITEM_ID = ORIGINAL.ITEM_ID
  AND TRUNC(MAX_VERSION.BUSINESS_DT) = TRUNC(ORIGINAL.BUSINESS_DT)
  AND TRUNC(MAX_VERSION.MAX_VERSION) = TRUNC(ORIGINAL.VERSION)
),
MAX_WITH_CORRECTED AS (
  SELECT ORIGINAL.ITEM_ID, ORIGINAL.ITEM_SUB_ID, ORIGINAL.BUSINESS_DT,ORIGINAL.REPORT_DT,
  ORIGINAL.VERSION, ORIGINAL.STATE, ORIGINAL.PRICE FROM ITEM_PRICE ORIGINAL
  JOIN (
    SELECT ITEM_ID, ITEM_SUB_ID, BUSINESS_DT, MAX(VERSION) MAX_VERSION FROM ITEM_PRICE 
    GROUP BY ITEM_ID, ITEM_SUB_ID, BUSINESS_DT) 
      MAX_VERSION
  ON NVL(MAX_VERSION.ITEM_SUB_ID,0) = NVL(ORIGINAL.ITEM_SUB_ID,0)
  AND MAX_VERSION.ITEM_ID = ORIGINAL.ITEM_ID
  AND TRUNC(MAX_VERSION.BUSINESS_DT) = TRUNC(ORIGINAL.BUSINESS_DT)
  AND TRUNC(MAX_VERSION.MAX_VERSION) = TRUNC(ORIGINAL.VERSION)
)

SELECT MAX_WITH_CORRECTED.* FROM MAX_WITH_CORRECTED INNER JOIN LATEST_ITEMS 
ON NVL(MAX_WITH_CORRECTED.ITEM_SUB_ID,0) = NVL(LATEST_ITEMS.ITEM_SUB_ID,0)
  AND MAX_WITH_CORRECTED.ITEM_ID = LATEST_ITEMS.ITEM_ID
  AND TRUNC(MAX_WITH_CORRECTED.BUSINESS_DT) = TRUNC(LATEST_ITEMS.BUSINESS_DT)
  AND TRUNC(MAX_WITH_CORRECTED.BUSINESS_DT) = '15-AUG-2023'
  ;
```

Sample Data;

```
CREATE TABLE ITEM_PRICE
       (ITEM_ID NUMBER(10), ITEM_SUB_ID NUMBER(10), BUSINESS_DT DATE, REPORT_DT DATE,
        VERSION NUMBER(3), STATE VARCHAR2(10), PRICE NUMBER(7,2)) ;

INSERT INTO ITEM_PRICE VALUES ( 100, 1000, '15-AUG-2023', '15-AUG-2023', 1, 'RECEIVED', 10 );
INSERT INTO ITEM_PRICE VALUES ( 100, 1000, '15-AUG-2023', '15-AUG-2023', 2, 'APPROVED', 20 );
INSERT INTO ITEM_PRICE VALUES ( 100, 1001, '15-AUG-2023', '15-AUG-2023', 1, 'RECEIVED', 10 );
INSERT INTO ITEM_PRICE VALUES ( 100, 1001, '15-AUG-2023', '15-AUG-2023', 2, 'APPROVED', 20 );
INSERT INTO ITEM_PRICE VALUES ( 101, NULL, '15-AUG-2023', '15-AUG-2023', 1, 'APPROVED', 10 );

INSERT INTO ITEM_PRICE VALUES ( 100, 1000, '16-AUG-2023', '16-AUG-2023', 1, 'RECEIVED', 10 );
INSERT INTO ITEM_PRICE VALUES ( 100, 1000, '16-AUG-2023', '16-AUG-2023', 2, 'RECEIVED', 20 );
INSERT INTO ITEM_PRICE VALUES ( 100, 1000, '16-AUG-2023', '16-AUG-2023', 3, 'APPROVED', 30 );
INSERT INTO ITEM_PRICE VALUES ( 100, 1000, '16-AUG-2023', '16-AUG-2023', 4, 'CORRECTED', 50 );
INSERT INTO ITEM_PRICE VALUES ( 100, 1001, '16-AUG-2023', '16-AUG-2023', 1, 'APPROVED', 10 );
INSERT INTO ITEM_PRICE VALUES ( 101, NULL, '16-AUG-2023', '16-AUG-2023', 1, 'RECEIVED', 10 );

INSERT INTO ITEM_PRICE VALUES ( 100, 1000, '15-AUG-2023', '16-AUG-2023', 3, 'CORRECTED', 15 );
INSERT INTO ITEM_PRICE VALUES ( 100, 1000, '15-AUG-2023', '16-AUG-2023', 4, 'CORRECTED', 18 );
INSERT INTO ITEM_PRICE VALUES ( 101, NULL, '15-AUG-2023', '16-AUG-2023', 2, 'CORRECTED', 20 );
```

Please add a comment if you need more details.

Answer (score 1):

Try it using MAX() OVER() analytic function like below. This way you need less code and it should be more effective. Not sure, though, as it depends on your actual context.

```sql
SELECT  ITEM_ID, ITEM_SUB_ID, BUSINESS_DT, REPORT_DT, STATE, PRICE, MAX(VERSION) "VERSION"
FROM (  SELECT    ITEM_ID, ITEM_SUB_ID, BUSINESS_DT, REPORT_DT, STATE, VERSION, PRICE, 
                  MAX(VERSION) OVER (Partition By ITEM_ID, ITEM_SUB_ID, BUSINESS_DT) "MAX_VERSION" 
        FROM      ITEM_PRICE 
     )
WHERE VERSION = MAX_VERSION And BUSINESS_DT = '15-AUG-23'  -- ('16-AUG-23')
GROUP BY ITEM_ID, ITEM_SUB_ID, BUSINESS_DT, REPORT_DT, STATE, PRICE
--  R e s u l t       15-AUG-23
--     ITEM_ID ITEM_SUB_ID BUSINESS_ REPORT_DT STATE           PRICE    VERSION
--  ---------- ----------- --------- --------- ---------- ---------- ----------
--         101             15-AUG-23 16-AUG-23 CORRECTED          20          2
--         100        1001 15-AUG-23 15-AUG-23 APPROVED           20          2
--         100        1000 15-AUG-23 16-AUG-23 CORRECTED          18          4


--  R e s u l t       16-AUG-23
--     ITEM_ID ITEM_SUB_ID BUSINESS_ REPORT_DT STATE           PRICE    VERSION
--  ---------- ----------- --------- --------- ---------- ---------- ----------
--         100        1000 16-AUG-23 16-AUG-23 CORRECTED          50          4
--         100        1001 16-AUG-23 16-AUG-23 APPROVED           10          1
--         101             16-AUG-23 16-AUG-23 RECEIVED           10          1
```

Result for '15-AUG-23' is the same as in your fiddle so it should be for '16-AUG-23' too. Try it and adjust to your actual data if needed.

```sql
/*
 Plan Hash Value  : 334110407 

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation              | Name       | Rows | Bytes | Cost | Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT       |            |    8 |   720 |    5 | 00:00:01 |
|   1 |   HASH GROUP BY        |            |    8 |   720 |    5 | 00:00:01 |
| * 2 |    VIEW                |            |    8 |   720 |    4 | 00:00:01 |
|   3 |     WINDOW SORT        |            |    8 |   616 |    4 | 00:00:01 |
| * 4 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL | ITEM_PRICE |    8 |   616 |    3 | 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
------------------------------------------
* 2 - filter("VERSION"="MAX_VERSION")
* 4 - filter("BUSINESS_DT"='15-AUG-23')
*/
```